# Xojo, MySQL, load data local infile, won't work in Xojo

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xojo

I am trying to run the "load data local infile" from within a Xojo app. If you don't know Xojo think of it as a Mac version of VB for this purpose. I have no problem running the SQL from Workbench on the same machine. I get error 1148, The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.

But why can I run the same command from Workbench on the same machine and it works?

Comment: You need to give more information. What, for instance, is *the "load data local infile"*? And post some sample code so that we can better tell what you're trying to do. I know a lot about Xojo but have not the slightest idea what you're talking about.

Comment: This is an issue with Xojo and needs to be addressed by them. I'm trying to upload a tab delimited text file directly to a MySQL table from a local computer hence "load data local infile". The server needs to be configured to receive files from local computers AND the application on local computer needs to configured to send a local file. Workbench and Sequel Pro both handle this. Xojo does not and there does not appear to be anyway to configure that at present.

Comment: If the contents of "load data local infile" are SQL then you CAN run it.   Look at SQLExecute  in the Xojo docs:   https://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Database.SQLExecute